# inline divs are not staying inline when content is placed inside them Chrome & Safari

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have 3 inline divs, with set width and height. They look great, then I add content inside one of the divs and all the sudden they don't line up any more in Chrome and Safari.  (They also never line up in IE6 & 7 I would love to understand that as well.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>What is going on?</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .actionBox
            {
                width: 295px;
                height: 215px;  
                margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: #BBB;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class='actionBox'>
                *** TAKE THIS LIKE OF TEXT OUT AND THEY WILL ALL LINE UP AGAIN ***
            </div>
            <div class='actionBox'>
            </div>
            <div class='actionBox'>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align`.  The default is `baseline` which is causing the bottom of the text to line up with the baseline. Try `top` or `bottom` and it should work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/aXesS/

In the fiddle, the first 3 are your code directly.  Notice that the bottoms of the text in each box are lining up.  The 2nd 3 are with `vertical-align:top`.  Notice that they are all nicely lined up.

Comment: Wow, first I have seen the jsfiddle thing.  Thats seems to work great.. Thank you.  Do you have any quick fixes so that it would work in IE 6 & 7 as well?

Comment: Change them to spans.  IE6 (and maybe 7) will only allow `inline-block` on elements which are natively inline.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block;` ?

Comment: I gave this a shot, but the page I am working with is a bit more complex than my example.  I really want the divs to fill out the div they are contained in.